# Range.find with date as argument

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a table (Lets call tb1) that has a date column.

I need to search in tb2 (which has a date on it) using tb1_date as key, and it must return tb2 row number where the same date is located

```
for i = 1 to tb1_length
    v1 = range("A" & i).value    'date from tb1, i is just a random row
    msgbox range("D1:D20").find(v1).row  'search for the row number in tb2 (say its D1:D20)
```

now this keeps me getting a runtime error 91 or similars whenever I use date as a search argument

I have tried transforming date type into long type (even formating it) with no success in the search

Answer (score 3):

If no match is found the return value of `Range.Find()` will be `Nothing` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) - The Expression `Find(v1).Row` is in such cases equivalent to `Nothing.Row`, which will cause Error 91 (Since the Object variable is not set)

If the value you are searching for doesn't exist `Find(v1)` will return `Nothing` hence causing the error

To solve this you have to check if your return is Nothing and only proceed with getting the row if it isn't

```
Dim match As Range

Set match = Range("D1:D20").Find(v1)
If Not match Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox (match.Row)
End If
```